# Went to Mexico and re-entered the USA within 1 hour by land

Tags: usa, i-94

I am on a non-immigrant visa (L1). I have been to Mexico by land and re-entered the USA within 1 hour by land. When I re-entered the USA at port of entry the immigration officer did not stamp anything in my passport. The officer said as I have a valid visa and I was good to enter. Today when I checked my travel history, only the departure has been recorded and not the arrival. Is this going to impact anything?

When I contacted CBP, the officer said as I have not crossed the territory and came back in time that should not be a problem. Now I am travelling to my home country for 1 month. Will this travel history (showing only departure not arrival) have an impact when I go back to the USA?

Comment: By "travel history" do you mean your online I-94 record?

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't have any issues from this. Many people visiting the US (or on work visas) take brief visits to Mexico or Canada. And you returned correctly through a border and were properly admitted. If you didn't get a new admission stamp, you are allowed to remain in the US until the date that was written on your previous admission stamp (or later, if you have applied for and received an extension).

When you leave the US to return to your home country, your departure will again be recorded. There is no exit immigration in the US; instead, the airline will notify CBP that you took a flight leaving the country. In order to return to the US from your home country, your *visa* must not be expired, or you must obtain a new visa. Returning on an expired visa is only possible [if you traveled to Canada or Mexico for 30 days or less, and are still in status](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors).